# SPContext.Current.Web.Url returns http instead of https

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, https, spcontext

I have developed several webparts, where i used SPContext.Current.Web.Url  to get the web url. It's working when access a site with hxxps://abc/ But i get http instead of https when accessed by IP.

**Problem:**
When i access hxxps://172.1.25.25/
SPContext.Current.Web.Url returns hxxp://172.1.25.25/

When i access hxxps://abc/
SPContext.Current.Web.Url returns hxxps://abc/

**My Alternate Access Mappings**

hxxp://172.1.25.25/ Intranet

hxxps://172.1.25.25/ Intranet

hxxp://abc/ Internet

hxxps://abc/ Internet

I used several workaround which i got it in the Forum :( nothing worked, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your AAM you will have one that is the "Public URL for zone" and this is what SPContext.Current.Web.URL will return - change it to https if that is the one you want to use.

SharePoint Central Admin > Application Management > Configure alternate Access Mappings > Edit Public URL's

[MSDN - Configure alternate access mapping (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173%28v=office.12%29.aspx)